# Libgdx there is one body without sprite

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, box2d

```
    int amoumt = 10;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < amoumt+1)
            {
                    box(1);//body
                    i++;
            }
```

If i use this method i get 9 bodies wits a sprite and one body without a sprite.
But i wand a sprite on all of them

In the render method, for drawing a sprite on **each** body:

```
batch.begin();
                            world.getBodies(worldBodies);
                            for (Body body : worldBodies) {
                            if (body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite) {
                            Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
                            Vector2 position = body.getPosition();
                            sprite.setPosition(position.x - sprite.getWidth() / 2,position.y - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
                            sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
                            sprite.draw(batch);
                            }
                            }
                            batch.end();
                        }
```

Body:

```
private Body box(float a) 
                    {
                            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
                            bodyDef.position.set(0,0);
                            bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
                            PolygonShape polygonShape=new PolygonShape();
                            polygonShape.setAsBox(a,a);
                            FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
                            fixtureDef.shape=polygonShape;
                            fixtureDef.density=2;
                            fixtureDef.restitution=0.5f;
                            fixtureDef.friction=0.5f;
                            Body box=world.createBody(bodyDef);
                            box.createFixture(fixtureDef);
                            box.setUserData(sprite);
                            sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("android.jpg"));
                            sprite.setSize(a*2,a*2);
                            sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
                            worldBodies = new Array<Body>();

                            return box;
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please include more source code to help explain what your box() method does. If this is where you create your "bodies," it is most likely where your problem lies. Also, are you using Box2D?

Comment: @Samich I edited the post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the sprite you're setting as the user data isn't initialized when you create your first box. Try moving the `sprite = new sprite` init lines before setting the user data to the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```
private Body box(float a) 
{
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.position.set(0,0);
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        PolygonShape polygonShape=new PolygonShape();
        polygonShape.setAsBox(a,a);
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape=polygonShape;
        fixtureDef.density=2;
        fixtureDef.restitution=0.5f;
        fixtureDef.friction=0.5f;
        Body box=world.createBody(bodyDef);
        box.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("android.jpg"));
        sprite.setSize(a*2,a*2);
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        box.setUserData(sprite);
        worldBodies = new Array<Body>();

        return box;
}
```

hope that was helpful !